# Use Icon property with embedded images in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a [shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) and I implemented a [Master Detail Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/pages/). Now I added an image to the shared project (aka [embedded image](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images)). The build action for the image is *Embedded resource* and I'm following the advice taking the namespace (HelloForms) and the subfolder (Ressources) into account. The result should be the following:

[image: http://www.xforms-kickstarter.com/SlideOutMenu/screenshot-menu.png]

As you can see the [`leftBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItem) is set through the `Icon` property. I tried to set the [`Icon`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/) property like the following:

```
Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "HelloForms.Ressources.menu.png" : null;
```

and

```
Icon = new FileImageSource { File = "HelloForms.Ressources.menu.png" };
```

Currently I get the title of the *Master* page shown instead of the `Icon`. What do I have to change to get this working? I'm interested in the solution of *embedded images* and less in *local images*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong, you want to use ImageSource.FromResource, that's explicitly created for that:

```
Icon = ImageSource.FromResource("HelloForms.Ressources.menu.png");
```

**EDIT:**

Icon is a FileStream so ImageSource cannot be used. Also, Xamarin did it for a good reason, that file will be used to represent the app on the desktop on Android so it must be accessible by the system and an embedded resource cannot be as it's inside a resource file.

"Embedded resource" is causing confusion here, on iOS projects Xamarin changed the default "Content" action to "Embedded resource", which leads to think it's being embedded in the .net assembly, but no, it's copied to the project.

Just add the file to the iOS/Android project as resource and use the file name directly.

Comment: I already tried that, but I get *Cannot implicitely convert type 'Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource' to 'Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource'*. In the links of my question you can see that `Icon` needs `FileImageSource`. Casting is not possible (the app crashes then).

Comment: Then you can't use a resource for feeding that property, the only thing which comes to my mind is to first copy the resource file to a local file and then use it... really ugly. Also, Xamarin did set this as a FileSource for a good reason, that icon will be used by the system (Android) to represent the app, so it must be accessible, a resource image is stored into the resource file and the system cannot access it.

Comment: The interesting part is that [this site](http://www.xforms-kickstarter.com/#a-slide-out-menu-using-a-master-detail-page) seems to do this with `Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null;`. So how would it look like if the image is embedded into the iOS project for example? Can I use the `Icon` property then?

Comment: Yes, that's the way, maybe "Embedded resource" is causing confusion here, on iOS projects Xamarin changed the default "Content" action to "Embedded resource", which leads to think it's being embedded in the .net assembly, but no, it's copied to the project. But here you're adding it to a shared project so I'm not sure if that changes the meant of the compile action. Try it.

Comment: Now I added *menu.png* to the *Resources* folder of the iOS project and now it gets displayed as mentioned on the site!

Answer (score -1):

*menu.png* was added to the shared project which is wrong. Adding it to the **Resources** folder of the iOS project (*Build Action = BundleResource*) seems to do the trick. Then you only need this code

```
Icon = Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS ? "menu.png" : null;
```

to make it work. Seems that I misunderstood *Embedded Images*.